# Why are drawables being pushed passed the edges of layout?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on a pin entry screen and the pin digit orbs are being scaled once their total width becomes greater than the content space available. But the first and final orb are pushing out of the content space and I can't figure out why.

This is an exmaple of the pin orbs pushing out the edges:

[image: This is an example of the pin orbs pushing out the edges]

Code:

```
    padViewHolder.addView(
            padView,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)

    padView.setPadActionListener(object : PadView.PadActionListener {
        override fun symbolPressed() {
            val digit = ImageView(pinPadDigitContainer.context)
            digit.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pin_digit_filled)
            if (noSpace) {
                noSpace = false
                pinPadDigitContainer.addView(digit)
                pinPadDigitContainer.resizeChildrenToFit()
            } else {
                val space = Space(context)
                pinPadDigitContainer.addView(space)
                pinPadDigitContainer.addView(digit)
                pinPadDigitContainer.resizeChildrenToFit()
                pinPadDigitContainer.invalidate()
            }
        }

private fun ViewGroup.resizeChildrenToFit() {
   val numOfOrbs = (childCount - 1) / 2
   val displayWidth = resources.displayMetrics.run { widthPixels / density }
   val singleSpace = calculatePercentageSpace(displayWidth).toInt() // 7% of screen width
   val widthOfOrb = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.ic_pin_digit_width) // 29dp
   val dpInt = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.ic_pin_orb_space) // 3dp
   val contentSpace = width - paddingLeft - paddingRight
   var childrenWidth = numOfOrbs * widthOfOrb + (singleSpace * (numOfOrbs - 1))

   if (childrenWidth <= contentSpace) {
    for (i in 0 until childCount) {
        calculateOrbAndSpaceWidth(i, widthOfOrb, singleSpace)
    }
   } else {
    childrenWidth = remain
    val smallOrb = contentSpace / numOfOrbs - 3

    for (i in 0 until childCount) {
        calculateOrbAndSpaceWidth(i, smallOrb, dpInt)
    }
}
```

}

This is the part of the view i'm working with:

```
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/meta__display2_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:clipChildren="true"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="5.5:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/meta__display1_s"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.56" />
```

Comment: try limiting it to 4 or 6 digit

Comment: I'm using 12 digit as a requirement for this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted the actual code where you calculate the scaled widths (`calculateOrbAndSpaceWidth`) but it looks like that's not being worked out correctly. Your code's a little hard for me to follow, so I can't really rework it, but can't you do something like this?

```
val orbWidth = // get default orb width
val spaceWidth = // get default space between orbs
val totalWidth = (orbWidth * orbCount) + (spaceWidth * (orbCount-1))

val availableWidth = // get width of view - padding
// Work out what scaling factor would make all the orbs fit the available space exactly.
// If they need to be scaled down (scale: less than 1.0) use that value, otherwise keep them
// at the current size (scale: 1.0)
val scaleFactor = minOf(1f, availableWidth / totalWidth.toFloat())
```

And then draw all your orbs with the *scale factor* applied to the orb dimensions, space widths, and any coordinate offsets. (I don't know how you're actually drawing them, but you're scaling them somehow!) When `scaleFactor` is `1.0` it'll draw everything as normal, when it's smaller it'll adjust all your measurements to make them fit.

---

Also make sure you're not mixing up *dp* and *px* measurements - you seem to be working with both. Personally I'd convert any of your *dp* values to pixels (which you're mostly doing) and just work with that. This part here:

`val displayWidth = resources.displayMetrics.run { widthPixels / density }`

Is taking the width of the window in *pixels* and converting it to *dp*. You only use it in this function call:

`val singleSpace = calculatePercentageSpace(displayWidth).toInt()`

so I can't see what you're doing with it - but you either that result to `calculateOrbAndSpaceWidth`, or `dpInt` (which is a *px* value), and you're getting expected results with one and unexpected with the other. So just make sure you're being consistent in there - might be fine, just pointing it out!

Comment: Thank you! this worked. Now that you've said it, it seems pretty obvious but scaling down the orbs worked. The problem I run into with scaling is it affected the spacing between the orbs. But based on your solution I adjusted the width of the container to always be 1 orb less to stop them pushing out of the edges:

val contentSpace = (width - paddingLeft - paddingRight) - widthOfOrb

Comment: @Rednuam oh my solution there assumes you want to scale the spacing down too (so you're kinda *zooming out* of the view to see the whole thing). That's what I'd normally expect to see (it looks more consistent) but if you do want to maintain your spacing, remove `(spaceWidth * (orbCount-1))` from `totalWidth` and subtract it from `availableWidth` instead. Basically the width you have *available for orbs* is the *view width - any padding - the width taken up by spacing*. Then you just scale your orbs to fit what's left

Comment: If you calculate it like that it should fit *exactly*, you shouldn't need to tweak it with a random extra bit of free space! It looks like you're taking padding into account correctly, so just make sure all the other calculations are correct. If you get the basic idea of how I've done this (it's pretty simple once you see it) then you should be able to check it over. Try setting a breakpoint in `onDraw` or something and debug the app, you can see what values are being calculated and check if there's a mistake somewhere (if you care I mean, if it's working for you then great!)

Comment: Man I really appreciate the detailed response.  You've really helped me figure this thing out as I seemed to be going in circles. Thanks.